# .htaccess redirect to subdomain with regex

Tags: .htaccess

I want to 301 redirect a specific path to another subdomain with htaccess

I want :

```
A : http://www.example.org/markets/access/id/56
B : http://www.example.org/markets/market/id/56
```

to redirect to :

```
A : https://archive.example.org/markets/access/id/56
B : https://archive.example.org/markets/market/id/56
```

I have tried this but get an error 500:

```
RewriteCond http://www.example.org/markets/(.+?)
RewriteRule https://archive.example.org/markets/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thank you

Comment: Your RewriteCond makes no sense. It needs at least two “parameters”, you have given only one. Instead of _guessing_ syntax, please go read up on it in the documentation.

Comment: Also, the first thing you should always do, when you get a 500, is go and check the error log, to find out what the actual reason for the error was.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure you put these rules at the top of your .htaccess file.

Also make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(example\.org)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://archive.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```